# MapBox Api 2.2 Country Polygons in Web

Tags: mapbox

We need to show countries with different colors using MapBox Api 2.2
Where do we find all countries data in geoJson format ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repository for the geojson is here - https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json . There are many others around the web as well.

You could then bring them into Mapbox with [featureLayer.setGeoJSON](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/load-geojson/)

Coloring can then happen with the usual Leaflet styles approach [`setStyle`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path-setstyle) . Although you could also do that during GeoJSON by using the properties hash I believe.